# Run time error while connecting to postgresql using SQLAPI++

Tags: c++, postgresql, sqlapi++

I'm very new to sqlapi++ . Based on the tutorial provided in the official website I tried connecting to postgresql database that is running on my system.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<SQLAPI.h>

void main()
{
  SAConnection con;

  try
  {
   con.Connect("localhost@postgres","postgres","12345",
       SA_PostgreSQL_Client);

   printf("We are connected");
  }

   catch(SAException &x)
  {
    printf("%s\n",(const char*)x.ErrText());
  }

  _getch();
}
```

I'm programming in Visual studio 2010, the include path points to SQLAPI/include directory and the same for library, I have used release version of static library sqlapis.lib. The program is building but when I run it it shows error as

**libpq.dll: The specified module could not be found.
pq.dll: The specified module could not be found.**

**DBMS API Library loading fails
This library is a part of DBMS client installation, not SQLAPI++
Make sure DBMS client is installed and
this required library is available for dynamic loading**

Can I know how to get rid of this ?

Comment: *The specified module could not be found. pq.dll* -- You're running an app that requires pq.dll, but that DLL cannot be found by your system.  So how do you get rid of this error?  Install the DLL that your app is looking for in the appropriate path / directory / etc.

Comment: The libpq.dll is found in the bin directory of postgresql installed directory, so I copied the dll and placed where the exe was built and the error changes to

libpq.dll: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Probably a 64-bit / 32-bit issue?  If you built a 64-bit app, the DLL's need to be 64-bit.  If it's a 32-bit app, the DLL's need to be 32-bit.  Mixing these up will cause issues like this.